# correct way to update a pandas dataframe with a shifted version of itself?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The below code appears to work, however I fail to understand why it's working and if it's correct/safe:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 100, 10).reshape(-1, 2), columns = list('ab'))
>>> df
    a   b
0  45  44
1  89  45
2  80  93
3  66  27
4  89  73
>>> df.at[1,'a']=0
>>> df.at[2,'a']=0
>>> df
    a   b
0  45  44
1   0  45
2   0  93
3  66  27
4  89  73
>>> df.loc[df['a']==0,'a'] = df['a'].shift(-2)
>>> df
    a   b
0  45  44
1  66  45
2  89  93
3  66  27
4  89  73
>>>
```

Why are the values updated as expected? (i.e. in [1,a] the value from [3,a] is copied in [2,a] the value of [4,a] is copied

Left side of the assignement is a subset of a dataframe column (i.e. a Series of 2 elements), right side of the assignment is a full column (a Series of 5 elements), so how does this assignment work?
Is the index of both sides of the assignment the same and is this used for the assignment?

Thx for any feed-back.

br,
Ruben

Answer (score 0):

In general I avoid using `.loc`, `.at` etc. if only because the code can end up a bit obtuse. You may find an expression involving the `where` function a tad clearer since by definition the purpose of `where` is to conditionally replace values.

```py
df['a'] = df['a'].where(df['a'] != 0, df['a'].shift(-2))
```

Comment: Hi Ray, thank you for your answer. It's not really the answer I was looking for, but it's a good alternative to the loc approach.
My original question is not applicable to your solution. In your solution both sides of the assignment are full Series.
In my loc approach I have a sub-selection of a Series being assigned to a full Series. Still unclear how that works.